# Javascript Image Replacement spotty in FF

Tags: javascript, dom, image

Any reason why this works every time in Safari but only SOME of the time in FF 3.6?

```
<ul id="row-0" class="row group">
    <li class="left thumb">
        <img id="img-1" src="img/ajax.gif" />
    </li>

    <li class="left thumb">
        <img id="img-2" src="img/ajax.gif" />
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    var flixThumbs = {
        thumbs: [
            { 
                src: "img/03.jpg",
                id: "img-03"
            },
            { 
                src: "img/04.jpg",
                id: "img-04"
            },
            { 
                src: "img/05.jpg",
                id: "img-05"
            },
            { 
                src: "img/06.jpg",
                id: "img-06"
            }
        ]
    }
    var imgID = document.getElementById('img-1');
    imgID.src = flixThumbs.thumbs[2].src;

    var imgID = document.getElementById('img-2');
    imgID.src = flixThumbs.thumbs[3].src;
</script>
```

The original ajax.gif is disappearing from the DOM but when I inspect with Firebug, I see that the new img tag that has replaced it is greyed out and not being displayed in the browser.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Since you're using firebug, look at the net tab.  Is the new image actually being downloaded?  What's the response code (200, 304, etc)?

Comment: I'm working from my own Desktop using assets that are stored locally which I guess means I'm not going to see anything in the Net Panel.  I know it's working because the first img loads just fine, but the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document may not be ready by the time the code is executed. Try it this way

```
window.onload = function() {
    var imgID = document.getElementById('img-1');
    imgID.src = flixThumbs.thumbs[2].src;

    var imgID = document.getElementById('img-2');
    imgID.src = flixThumbs.thumbs[3].src;
}
```

Comment: That's still not working.  I have even done it using timers that wait 5 seconds before attempting the change and that only gives me the same result.

Comment: his script is at the bottom of the document, so the document is loaded.  It doesn't matter if it's fully loaded because the elements he's using are.

Comment: As it turns out the images, when viewed separately in the browser, were noted as not being able to display properly because of errors.  I tried different images and they seem to be working fine.  Strange because Safari has no problem.  Thanks for everyone's time with this!